# Trigger SQL insert and update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two table `INVENTORY` and `INPUT`

```
create table INPUT(
PRODUCTID nvarchar(10),
QUANTUMINPUT int
)

create table INVENTORY(
PRODUCTID nvarchar(10),
QUANTUM int,
QUANTUMINPUT int,
LASTQUANTUM int
)
```

How to create SQL `trigger` on SQL when insert column `QUANTUMINPUT`, table `INVENTORY` change over?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the FAQ section, especially How to ask page. Also please state the purpose of the columns you are using and the trigger that you want to code.

Comment: Why do so many people keep tagging both `mysql` and `sql-server`? Does anybody even read the pop-ups for the tags they're choosing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create trigger tr_update_insert_input
On dbo.[input]
After insert, update 
As 
Begin 
 Set nocount on; 

 Update intry
  Set intry.quantumnput = inpt.quantuminput
 From inventory intry inner join inserted inpt
 On intry.productid = inpt.productid 

End
```